# I can't get which two assignment drives are conflicted together

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I tried to make the watch that counts the time given that cycle of clk is a minute.
But, I had troubles with finding which two assignment are being clashed.
(I have been looking for two days but I couldn't find it)

First I tried these codes in the EDA playground.

```
//code for "design.sv"

module clock(
  input clk, rstn,
  output reg[6:0] minute,      //line 1
  output reg[5:0] hour         //line 2
);

  
  always @ (posedge clk, negedge rstn) begin
    if(!rstn) begin
        minute <= 0; hour = 0;
        end
    else begin
        minute = minute + 1;
        end
  end
  
  always @ (posedge clk) begin
    if((minute%60==0)&&(minute != 0)) begin
        minute <= 0;
        hour = hour + 1;
        end
    
    if((hour%24==0)&&(hour !=0)) hour <= 0;
  end
  
  
endmodule
```

```
//code for "testbench.sv"
module test;
  reg clk, rstn;
  reg [6:0] minute;
  reg [5:0] hour;
  
  initial begin
    clk = 0;
    forever #5 clk = ~clk;
  end
  
  initial begin
    rstn = 1; minute = 0; hour = 0;    //line 3
    #30 rstn = 0;
    #1 rstn = 1;
    #600 $finish;
  end
  
  clock clock_inst(clk, rstn, minute, hour);
  
  initial begin
    $dumpfiles("wave.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0, test);
  end
  
endmodule
```

I simulated these first codes and got the error below.

> "Variable ""minute"" cannot be driven by both the procedural and continuous assignment statements.
> "Variable ""hour"" cannot be driven by both the procedural and continuous assignment statements.

My first conclusion:
I concluded that assignments on `line 1` and `line 2` are making conflict with those of `line 3`.
I thought `output reg minute` and `output reg hour` in `clock_inst` are implicit continuous assignment.
Accordingly `line 1` and `line 2` clashes with assignments on `minute` and `hour`(placed in `line 3`) leading to multidriver issue in one variable.

However, in order to check my conclusion, I revised the code like below.

```
//revised code for "design.sv"

module clock(
  input clk, rstn,
  output reg[6:0] minute, 
  output reg[5:0] hour
);

  
  initial begin        // newly added block
    minute = 0; hour = 0;
  end
  
  always @ (posedge clk, negedge rstn) begin
    if(!rstn) begin
        minute <= 0; hour = 0;
        end 
    else begin
        minute = minute + 1;
        end
  end
  
  always @ (posedge clk) begin
    if((minute%60==0)&&(minute != 0)) begin
        minute <= 0;
        hour = hour + 1;
        end
    
    if((hour%24==0)&&(hour !=0)) hour <= 0;
  end
  
  
endmodule
```

```
//revised code for "testbench.sv"

module test;
  reg clk, rstn;
  reg [6:0] minute;
  reg [5:0] hour;
  
  initial begin
    clk = 0;
    forever #5 clk = ~clk;
  end
  
  initial begin
    rstn = 1;          //revised line
    #30 rstn = 0;
    #1 rstn = 1;
    #600 $finish;
  end
  
  clock clock_inst(clk, rstn, minute, hour);
  
  initial begin
    $dumpfiles("wave.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0, test);
  end
  
endmodule
```

What I thought is that these codes would give me error because assignment on `newly added block` would be clashed with `output reg[6:0] minute` and `output reg[5:0] hour` assignments.

But it worked really well

> ## VSIM: Simulation has finished. There are no more test vectors to simulate.
>
> ## VSIM: Simulation has finished.

Now, I cannot find what lines constigate multi-driving error in my first code.

Comment: You drive minute in two places 'minute <=' . Does behavior improve if you move your logic into a single always block (instead of competing simultaneous processes)?

Comment: I will try to combine two seperate always block into one always block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original code, variable (reg) `minute` is driven from more than one `always` block.

That is the definition multiple drivers, and will not synthesize.

The solution is to put all drivers to the variables (regs) in one always block.
Like this:

```
  always @ (posedge clk, negedge rstn) begin
    if(!rstn) begin
       minute <= 0;
       hour   <= 0;
    end
    
    else begin

        if(minute < 60) 
          minute <= minute + 1;
        else
          minute <= 0;

        if(minute < 24) 
          hour   <= hour + 1;
        else
          hour   <= 0;
      
    end
  end
```

The modulus operator will not synthesize well except in cases where you are taking a modulus which is a power of 2^N example: 2,4,8,16,32...

Also take care to always use non-blocking assignments `<=` in a synchronous always block rather than blocking assignments `=`. Using blocking assignments in a synchronous always block can cause simulation/ synthesis mismatched behavior.

What you are seeing in the revised code is an example of the simulator not correctly detecting the multiple drivers associated with the verilog `always` block in simulation.   The SystemVerilog statement `always_ff` corrects this and will consistently detect a multiple drivers error in simulation and synthesis.

To demonstrate, I changed the `always` blocks to `always_ff` and re-ran on eda playground.
Like this:

```
module clock(
  input clk, rstn,
  output reg[6:0] minute, 
  output reg[5:0] hour
);

  
  initial begin        // newly added block
    minute = 0; hour = 0;
  end
  
  always_ff @ (posedge clk, negedge rstn) begin
    if(!rstn) begin
        minute <= 0; hour = 0;
        end 
    else begin
        minute = minute + 1;
        end
  end
  
  always_ff @ (posedge clk) begin
    if((minute%60==0)&&(minute != 0)) begin
        minute <= 0;
        hour = hour + 1;
        end
    
    if((hour%24==0)&&(hour !=0)) hour <= 0;
  end
  
endmodule
```

Produces:

```
    xmelab: *E,MULAXX (./design.sv,13|10): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable minute detected.
      always_ff @ (posedge clk, negedge rstn) begin
              |
    xmelab: *E,MULAXX (./design.sv,13|10): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable minute detected.
      always_ff @ (posedge clk, negedge rstn) begin
              |
    xmelab: *E,MULAXX (./design.sv,13|10): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable minute detected.
      always_ff @ (posedge clk, negedge rstn) begin
              |
    xmelab: *E,MULAXX (./design.sv,13|10): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable minute detected.
      always_ff @ (posedge clk, negedge rstn) begin
              |
    xmelab: *E,MULAXX (./design.sv,13|10): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable minute detected.
      always_ff @ (posedge clk, negedge rstn) begin
              |
    xmelab: *E,MULAXX (./design.sv,13|10): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable minute detected.
      always_ff @ (posedge clk, negedge rstn) begin
              |
    xmelab: *E,MULAXX (./design.sv,13|10): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable minute detected.
      always_ff @ (posedge clk) begin
              |
    xmelab: *E,MULAXX (./design.sv,22|10): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable minute detected.
      always_ff @ (posedge clk) begin
              |
    xmelab: *E,MULAXX (./design.sv,22|10): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable minute detected.
      always_ff @ (posedge clk) begin
              |
    xmelab: *E,MULAXX (./design.sv,22|10): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable minute detected.
      always_ff @ (posedge clk) begin
              |
    xmelab: *E,MULAXX (./design.sv,22|10): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable minute detected.
      always_ff @ (posedge clk) begin
              |
    xmelab: *E,MULAXX (./design.sv,22|10): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable minute detected.
      always_ff @ (posedge clk) begin
              |
    xmelab: *E,MULAXX (./design.sv,22|10): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable minute detected.
      always_ff @ (posedge clk) begin
              |
    xmelab: *E,MULAXX (./design.sv,22|10): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable minute detected.
      always_ff @ (posedge clk, negedge rstn) begin
              |
    xmelab: *E,MULAXX (./design.sv,13|10): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable hour detected.
      always_ff @ (posedge clk, negedge rstn) begin
              |
    xmelab: *E,MULAXX (./design.sv,13|10): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable hour detected.
      always_ff @ (posedge clk, negedge rstn) begin
              |
    xmelab: *E,MULAXX (./design.sv,13|10): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable hour detected.
      always_ff @ (posedge clk, negedge rstn) begin
              |
    xmelab: *E,MULAXX (./design.sv,13|10): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable hour detected.
      always_ff @ (posedge clk, negedge rstn) begin
              |
    xmelab: *E,MULAXX (./design.sv,13|10): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable hour detected.
      always_ff @ (posedge clk, negedge rstn) begin
              |
    xmelab: *E,MULAXX (./design.sv,13|10): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable hour detected.
      always_ff @ (posedge clk) begin
              |
    xmelab: *E,MULAXX (./design.sv,22|10): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable hour detected.
      always_ff @ (posedge clk) begin
              |
    xmelab: *E,MULAXX (./design.sv,22|10): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable hour detected.
      always_ff @ (posedge clk) begin
              |
    xmelab: *E,MULAXX (./design.sv,22|10): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable hour detected.
      always_ff @ (posedge clk) begin
              |
    xmelab: *E,MULAXX (./design.sv,22|10): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable hour detected.
      always_ff @ (posedge clk) begin
              |
    xmelab: *E,MULAXX (./design.sv,22|10): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable hour detected.
      always_ff @ (posedge clk) begin
              |
    xmelab: *E,MULAXX (./design.sv,22|10): Multiple drivers to always_ff output variable hour detected.
    xrun: *E,ELBERR: Error during elaboration (status 1), exiting.
```

Using Cadence and similar using Modelsim/Questa.

`always_ff` caught the multiple drivers and `always` missed it in simulation.

Comment: Thank you really much spending your time on this question. But, I didn't get this because same problem exists on revised codes, and these do not give me error.

Comment: Simulation tools may or may not identify and error out multiple drivers in always blocks. System Verilog added a new statement called always_ff to replace the always block which will constantly identify and error out on variables driven in more than one always block even in simulation. The revised code will not synthesize, and will produce multiple driver errors in synthesis. Same with an initial block and an always block using verilog 2005; simulation may or may not complain.

Comment: Thank you again for your great advice! I will find error that may not be caught during simulation process.(By using always_ff instead of always). Have a great day!